wrong Az.Acoounts version being used
I have these tasks in a pipeline I'm using that is failing because it is using Az.Accounts version earlier than 2.19.0 (2.17.0)
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Install Az.Accounts'
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 2.19.0 -Repository PSGallery -Force
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Export Cost Datea
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    azureSubscription: $serviceconnection
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    scriptType: 'inlineScript'
    inline: |
      Update-Module -Name "Az.Accounts" -Force 
      Get-InstalledModule -Name "Az.Accounts"
      Get-Module -ListAvailable
      $azTenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
      Write-host (Get-AzTenant | where-object Id -eq $azTenantId).Name
      Install-Module Az.CostManagement -Scope CurrentUser -Force
      Import-Module Az.CostManagement
      Invoke-AzCostManagementExecuteReport -ExportName $costExport -Scope $scope

Essentially its just the invoke cost management export and all the other code is just there to get it to work. I can see that both versions are installed when I list the modules. How do I make the pipeline use the correct version?
I tried using this fix Azure Devops pipeline failing due to AZ.Accounts Module update by MSFT but it is no longer working.
I also added the update module Line but it hasnt worked either and its still throwing the error:

This module requires Az.Accounts version 2.19.0. An earlier version of Az.Accounts is imported in the current PowerShell session. Please open a new session before importing this module. This error could indicate that multiple incompatible versions of the Azure PowerShell cmdlets are installed on your system. Please see https://aka.ms/azps-version-error for troubleshooting information.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.






its still throwing the error - please add the error message to your question.

Update: this error was fixed by switching from windows-latest to ubuntu-latest, does anyone know why this is?

The default versions of Az.Accounts on ubuntu-latest and windows-latest are both 2.17.0.
Using Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 2.19.0 -Repository PSGallery -Force to install the module Az.Accounts 2.19.0, it works fine whether using ubuntu-latest or windows-latest in my pipeline.
You can try again with windows-latest and share the error message, if any.

Update
You can use azure powershell 11.6.0. The version of Az.Accounts in azure powershell 11.6.0 is 2.19.0 by default. Replace azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion with preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '11.6.0' in your AzurePowerShell@5 task.

I still get the same problems shown above, is it possible there is a permissions issue that won't let the newer version be imported?

I am not sure about it. I can see WARNING: The version '2.19.0' of module 'Az.Accounts' is currently in use.  in the log when using windows-latest. The strange thing is that you are using a variable in service connection, azureSubscription: $serviceconnection, which is not supported. How did you make the pipeline to run?

I actually used ${{ variables.service_connection }} in the actual code I just had it like that here to save time as I thought it was irrelevant to the problem

I still can't reproduce the error This module requires Az.Accounts version 2.19.0... using the yaml shared by you. You can use azure powershell 11.6.0 in windows-latest and check if it works. The version of Az.Accounts in azure powershell 11.6.0 is 2.19.0 by default. Replace azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion with preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '11.6.0' in your AzurePowerShell@5 task. You can remove the scripts used to install Az.Accounts 2.19.0.

this worked, do you have any idea why the windows-latest wouldn't let me import the later version though? otherwise I'm happy to accept this answer

It's great az 11.6.0 works for you. To help others who have the same problem, I have added the solution to the answer above.  "do you have any idea why the windows-latest wouldn't let me import the later version though" - I don't have any ideas at the moment. This is strange because I can install and use 2.19.0 using Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts when the pipeline runs on windows-latest...

This looks like a repeatable issue, see https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/2745
It sounds like most users got a temporary workaround by downgrading Microsoft.Graph.Applications to 2.17.0
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications -Force -AllowClobber -RequiredVersion 2.17.0

